# Как выделить текст в input по клику в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Это не работает. И почему?

```
 ...

 selected(){
   this.selected();
 }

 render(){
    return(
      <input type="text" onClick={this.selected}/>
    )
 }
```

Comment: Почему бесконечная рекурсия должна работать?

Answer (score 3):

> Это не работает. И почему?

*Ответ по комментарию: у Вас бесконечная рекурсия.*

Если я правильно понял, Вам нужно при клике на `input` выделить всё содержимое в нём?

**Вот решение:**

```js
...

handleSelect = (e) => {
  e.target.select();
};

render() {
  return (
    <input type="text" onClick={this.handleSelect} />
  );
}
  
...
```

Если Вам удобнее, то можете посмотреть на CodeSandBox: [ссылка](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jnzv1kjww)